# How can I know how to interpret the output coefficients (`coefs_`) from the model sklearn.svm.LinearSVC()?

Tags: python, visualization, scikit-learn, svm, parameter

I'm following *Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists* by Andreas C. Müller and Sarah Guido, and in Chapter 2 a demonstration of applying `LinearSVC()` is given.  The result of classifying three blobs is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

The three blobs are obviously correctly classified, as depicted by the colored output.

My question is **how are we supposed to know how to interpret the model fit output** in order to draw the three lines?  The output parameters are given by

```
print(LinearSVC().fit(X,y).coef_)
[[-0.17492286  0.23139933]
 [ 0.47621448 -0.06937432]
 [-0.18914355 -0.20399596]]

print(LinearSVC().fit(X,y).intercept_)
[-1.07745571  0.13140557 -0.08604799]
```

And the authors walk us through how to draw the lines:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC  
linear_svm = LinearSVC().fit(X,y)  
...
line = np.linspace(-15, 15)  
for coef, intercept in zip(linear_svm.coef_, linear_svm.intercept_):  
    plt.plot(line, -(line * coef[0] + intercept) / coef[1])  #HOW DO WE KNOW
plt.ylim(-10, 15)  
plt.xlim(-10, 8)  
plt.show()
```

The line of code with the comment is the one that converts our coefficients into a slope/intercept pair for the line:

```
y = -(coef_0 / coef_1) x - intercept/coef_1
```

where the term in front of `x` is the slope and `-intercept/coef_1` is the intercept.  In the [documentation on LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html), the `coef_` and `intercept_` are just called "attributes" but don't point to any indicator that `coef_0` is the slope and `coef_1` is the negative of some overall scaling.

**How can I look up the interpretation of the output coefficients of this model and others similar to it in Scikit-learn without relying on examples in books and StackOverflow?**

Comment: I think the only hint is that is says, the coefficients belong to the primal problem which is briefly stated in the user guide under 1.4.7.1. It then follows probably more or less from the definition of the separating hyperplane. If your question is whether there are some more details about the coef_ attributes, then the answer is probably no. The documentation, in general, is not very detailed regarding implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one (admittedly hard) way.

If you really want to understand the low-level details, you can always work through the source code. For example, we can see that the `LinearSVC` `fit` method [calls `_fit_liblinear`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L210). That [calls `train_wrap` in liblinear](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/668a24c9e6e1a541bede64819612fdb5e169a341/sklearn/svm/base.py#L884), which gets everything ready to [call into the C++ function `train`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4d9a12d175a38f2bcb720389ad2213f71a3d7697/sklearn/svm/liblinear.pyx#L55).

So [`train` in linear.cpp](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4d9a12d175a38f2bcb720389ad2213f71a3d7697/sklearn/svm/src/liblinear/linear.cpp#L2364) is where the heavy lifting begins. Note that the `w` member of the model struct in the train function gets mapped back to `coef_` in Python.

Once you understand exactly what the underlying `train` function does, it should be clear exactly what `coef_` means and why we draw the lines that way.

While this can be a little laborious, once you get used to doing things this way, you will really understand how everything works from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

`y = -(coef_0 / coef_1) x - intercept/coef_1` is
`coef_0 x + coef_1 y + intercept = 0`, which is the border line separating the blob from the rest. `(coef_0, coef_1)` is the normal vector and the direction indicates where the blob is.

Comment: Yup, by seeing that equation we can figure out what the coefficients mean.  My question is how could we have known that without looking at the example in the Müller/Guido book and back it out?